# Cannot Launch `gksudo` using NodeJs `exec`

Tags: node.js, execution, gksudo

### Goal

I want to show graphical password prompt in nodejs to elevate priviledge thus gain some power to copy file content into another, but the last is owned by root.

In the implementation, I try to execute `dd` along with it's argument with `gksudo` with `exec()` function.

```
exec = require('child_process').exec

printall = function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
  console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
  if (error) {
    console.log('exec err: ' + error);
  }
}

exec("gksudo dd if=/home/user/minor.txt of=/home/user/major.txt", printall)
```

### Error

But I always fail, with no good reason.

It said,

```
stdout: 
stderr: 
exec err: Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c gksudo dd if=/home/user/minor.txt of=/home/user/major.txt
```

If I reproduce the command into terminal, it missed double quotes and instead run `gksudo` only. Well, in nodejs, it simply fails.

### Notes

I originally develop Atom package. It's my first time, so, I found out about a different version of Node (or IOJs?). I execute the whole code inside Atom.

### Question

If you expect a clear question, well, possibly

> How to execute `gksudo` within node.js to run other command along with the arguments?

Comment: You were talking about missing double quotes, did you try adding them with \"?

Comment: There also seems to be a npm module for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sudo

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Yes I've try adding it, but automatically `exec()` execute without `-c` option; leading to another error. The package sudo seems to work using console, as neither error nor dialog appear prompting for password.

Comment: What is the operating system? Did you try executing without the sudo? Did you try the [sync](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_synchronous_process_creation) version? What about `fork()` or `spawn()?`